# Grails 3.0.10 can't resolve MockFor

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I'm trying to port an existing Grails 2.2 plugin to Grails 3.0. As such, I would prefer to avoid rewriting its unit tests, which use `MockFor`

Having created a new 3.0.10 plugin with `grails create-plugin`, and copied the source files into the appropriate new locations, when I run `grails test-app` I get:

```
{path}/FooControllerTests.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
 @ line 4, column 1.
 import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
 ^
```

I haven't yet done anything to `build.gradle`.

```
$ grails --version
| Grails Version: 3.0.10
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.7.0_91
```

... the Groovy 2.4.5 API docs show `groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor` should be present: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.5/html/gapi/index.html?groovy/mock/interceptor/MockFor

What am I missing?

---

EDIT:

Modifying gradle.properties and changing `grailsVersion` to `3.0.9` seems to work (regardless of whether I tell SDK to use 3.0.9 or 3.0.10).

Comment: It would be great if you could create a sample application over github and share the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  A plugin was pulling in a older version of Groovy (2.3.X).  I had to find it and exclude the groovy required by that plugin.

My *build.gradle* file now has this:

```
compile("org.gebish:geb-junit4:0.10.0") {
  exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
}
```

I found this with the **gradle dependencies** command.  I looked for the *groovy-all* entries and found the plugin that forced an older version of groovy.